# Htaccess in main directory conflicts with subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, opencart

I'm using two different opensource systems for a customer.
On the main directory I've installed wordpress.
In a sub directory (/shop) I've installed OpenCart 1.5.5

I want to have SEO url's enabled in OpenCart but when I enable this, my url becomes:
www.example.com/shop/category
The main htaccess from wordpress then checks if it knows the category and the post in wordpress and returns a 404.

If someone has got a solution for me I would be very pleased!
Thank you for your effort!

HTACCESS from Wordpress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

HTACCESS from opencart:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the `RewriteBase` directive in the OpenCart `.htaccess` to

```
RewriteBase /shop/
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this works as I don't have a way of testing this locally. Change Wordpress htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```